# WPF : Finding a control in a resource

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, controls

i'd like to get a control in resource. but it's difficult for me.

**1. resource(xaml)**

```
<Span x:Key="spanParagrahTitle" x:Shared="false">
    <InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Center">
        <dgWPFCtrl:IconButton x:Name="ibtnAddToFavorite" Cursor="Hand" IsPressible="True"/>
    <InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Center">
</Span>
```

**2. code**

```
Span myTitle = (Span)appRes["spanParagrahTitle"];
IconButton ibtnAddToFavorite = (IconButton)myTitle.FindName("ibtnAddToFavorite");
```

How can I get control ibtnAddToFavorite in xaml?
of cause, FindName was failed. (It returns null.)

ps. IconButton is User Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have instantiated your Span, you should be able to use [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) to drill down the visual tree and get to your IconButton.

Comment: Thanks for giving a clue to me. A best way for soling this problem is LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode() method.

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you have provided, I can see dgWPFCtrl:IconButton is not a Resource. Its a Child of InlineUIContainer which in turn is part of resource called "spanParagrahTitle"

So the way to access that is

```
Span myTitle = (Span)appRes["spanParagrahTitle"]; 
IconButton ibtnAddToFavorite = ((InlineUIContainer)(myTitle.Content)).Content as IconButton;
```